# Scaling with subfloat/subfigure

Tags: floats, subfloats, scaling

How to scale multiple subfigure/subfloats such that the largest of the pictures is properly matched to the textwidth and all others are sclaled in the same proportion as the largest. The background is that all pictures include fonts and it is required that the font-size is equal in all subpictures?

Is there an elegant way using the standart way of representing figures in lates?

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[scale=1]{abb/1.pdf}} \\
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[scale=1]{abb/2.pdf}} \\
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[scale=1]{abb/3.pdf}} \\
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[scale=1]{abb/4.pdf}}
    \caption{}
    \label{UpDown}
\end{figure}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution uses saveboxes to measure the widths, and pgfmath to compute the scale.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=30in, margin=1in]{geometry}% to fit images on page
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{pgfmath}
\newlength{\maxwidth}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
  \sbox0{\includegraphics{example-image}}\maxwidth=\wd0
  \sbox1{\includegraphics{example-image-golden-upright}}\ifdim\wd1>\maxwidth \maxwidth=\wd1 \fi
  \sbox2{\includegraphics{example-image-10x16}}\ifdim\wd2>\maxwidth \maxwidth=\wd2 \fi
  \sbox3{\includegraphics{example-image-9x16}}\ifdim\wd3>\maxwidth \maxwidth=\wd3 \fi
  \pgfmathdivide{\linewidth}{\maxwidth}%
    \centering
    \subfloat[]{\scalebox{\pgfmathresult}{\usebox0}} \\
    \subfloat[]{\scalebox{\pgfmathresult}{\usebox1}} \\
    \subfloat[]{\scalebox{\pgfmathresult}{\usebox2}} \\
    \subfloat[]{\scalebox{\pgfmathresult}{\usebox3}}
    \caption{}
    \label{UpDown}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Works perfekt, that you! I use scrbook and i have used '\usepackage{geometry}% to fit images on page' instead of '\usepackage[paperheight=30in, margin=1in]{geometry}% to fit images on page'

Comment: The geometry was not part of the solution, just there to fit the 4 example images on one page.